# My iPhone 4s has no apps or photos but still saying memory is full

Tags: iphone, storage

My iPhone 4s has iOS version 7.1. I have deleted everything thing off of my iPhone and it is still saying I have used 5.6 GB out of my 6 GB total. Is there anyway to fix this? I have tried resetting it and it doesn't work.

Comment: Deleted not delayed

Answer (score -1):

my Iphone 4 has done the same thing before; try keeping it on until it runs out of power so that it turns off completly. then plug it in and turn it back on. also make sure that no webpages are open on the safari app. I hope that his is helpful.